# I need to generate this XML file in C# but I can't

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml

```
conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=127.0.0.1;Initial Catalog=TestLang;Integrated Security=True");
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(
      "SELECT * FROM Employee; SELECT * FROM Tbl_Translate", conn);
            adapter.TableMappings.Add("Table", " ");
            adapter.TableMappings.Add("Table1", " ");

conn.Open();
adapter.Fill(ds);
conn.Close();

ds.DataSetName = "TOURLIST";

ds.WriteXml(@"C:\Te\Xml1.xml");
richTextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Te\Xml1.xml");
```

This code generate this file

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<TOURLIST>
     <ID>1</ID>
     <FirstName> mohammad </FirstName>
     <LastName>neshasteh</LastName>
     <Designation>no</Designation>

     <ID>2</ID>
     <FirstName>ali</FirstName>
     <LastName />
     <Designation>Has</Designation>

     <ID>3</ID>
     <FirstName>ace</FirstName>
     <LastName>eca</LastName>
     <Designation />
</TOURLIST>
```

but I want export this format

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<TOURLIST>
     <ID>1</ID>
     <FirstName>mohammad</FirstName>
     <LastName>neshasteh</LastName>
     <Designation>no</Designation>
     <ID>2</ID>
     <FirstName>ali</FirstName>
     <LastName />
     <Designation>Has</Designation>
     <ID>3</ID>
     <FirstName>ace</FirstName>
     <LastName>eca</LastName>
     <Designation />
</TOURLIST>
```

Comment: // but I want export this Format
  


>     <TOURLIST>
>         <ID>1</ID>
>         <FirstName>mohammad</FirstName>
>         <LastName>neshasteh</LastName>
>         <Designation>no</Designation>
>         <ID>2</ID>
>         <FirstName>ali</FirstName>
>         <LastName />
>         <Designation>Has</Designation>
>         <ID>3</ID>
>         <FirstName>ace</FirstName>
>         <LastName>eca</LastName>
>         <Designation />
>       </TOURLIST>

Comment: Please don't post code or important information in comment, edit your question to include that instead.

Comment: I don't see any differences between the XML you have and the XML you say you want ...... what is wrong / not good with the XML you have?? Please **explain** and don't just dump two XML snippets on us, letting us **guess** what you might want to change....

Comment: The only difference in resultant and expected output is a new line between records. is it ?? or something else

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its not the neatest approach but you could loop through your xml and build up the string.

```
public static string GetFormat(string xmlString)
{
    var xml = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    BuildString(xml, builder);

    return builder.ToString();
}

public static void BuildString(XContainer container, StringBuilder builder)
{
    var element = container as XElement;

    if (element != null && !element.HasElements && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(element.Value))
    {
        builder.Append(element.Value + " ");
    }

    foreach (var xElement in container.Elements())
    {
        BuildString(xElement, builder);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just use ```string.Join("",XDocument.Parse(xmlString).Elements().Where(element => element != null && !element.HasElements && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(element.Value)).InDocumentOrder())```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you have 2 tables in your dataset?

so, instead of:

```
ds.WriteXml(@"C:\Te\Xml1.xml");
```

try something like:

```
ds.Tables(0).WriteXml(@"C:\Te\Xml1.xml");
```

or:

```
ds.Tables("tableName").WriteXml(@"C:\Te\Xml1.xml");
```

hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

another approach is to generate the xml in sql and then writing the result into an xml file. the code below is in t-sql:

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM dbo.Employee
FOR XML AUTO
```